# Netsuite Beforesubmit/Aftersubmit script not saving

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am New to Netsuite.

I am trying to archive the following functionality,

1. I created a code that will create an Invoice through API - (Completed & worked).
2. I want to change the Tax values to zoho for the Invoice that is created through the above.(ISSUE)

Here is my following code:

```
define(['N/log'], function (log) {

    /**
     * User Event 2.0 example showing usage of the Submit events
     *
     * @NApiVersion 2.x
     * @NModuleScope SameAccount
     * @NScriptType UserEventScript
     * @appliedtorecord customer
     */
    var exports = {};

    function beforeSubmit(context) {
            
          try
            {
        var currentRecord = context.newRecord;
 log.debug({
            title: 'currentRecord', 
            details: currentRecord
        });
              
            var sublistName = "item";
            var sublistFieldName = "taxcode";
            var line = context.line;
        var subsidiary_id = currentRecord.getValue({fieldId:'subsidiary'});
            var inv_type = currentRecord.getText({
            fieldId: 'custbody3'
            });
                     log.debug({
            title: 'inv_type', 
            details: inv_type
        });
                             log.debug({
            title: 'subsidiary_id', 
            details: subsidiary_id
        });
              
      if (subsidiary_id == 6)
      {
        if (inv_type == "Services") {
      
            if (sublistName === 'item') {
              
                var lines = currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'});
           log.debug({title:'lines',details:lines});     
            for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
                    var descriptionValue = currentRecord.getSublistValue({
                            sublistId: sublistName,
                            fieldId: "description",
                             line: i
                        })
                 
                  
                             log.debug({
            title: 'descriptionValue', 
            details: descriptionValue
        });
                             log.debug({title: 'sets',details: /NON-JP/ig.test(currentRecord.getSublistValue({
                            sublistId: sublistName,
                            fieldId: "description",
                     line: i
                        }))});
                  
                  
                if (/JP/ig.test(currentRecord.getSublistValue({
                            sublistId: sublistName,
                            fieldId: "description",
                      line: i
                        })))
                     {
                 
                
                        currentRecord.setSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'taxcode',
                        value: 6880,
                        ignoreFieldChange: true,
                        enableSourcing: true,
                           line: i
                    });
                     currentRecord.setSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'taxrate1',
                        value: "10.0",
                        ignoreFieldChange: true,
                        enableSourcing: true,
                        line: i
                    });
                      
                     }
             currentRecord.setSublistValue('item', 'taxrate1', i, 10.0);
            }
            }
        }
    }   
        
        } catch (e) {
             log.error('Error in validateLine', e);
                
            }
    }
    return {
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
    };
});
```

The Code logic and getValue method and other functionalities are working perfectly **Except for submit**

I tried to submit the newlyu updated line value in netsuite but the record is not getting submitted.

Can you help me to identify the issue I am doing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ignoreFieldChange` and `enableSourcing` parameters from your `setSublistValue` calls.  I am not sure if your logging statements will work -- we typically always convert the `details` field to a string before logging, by using something like `JSON.stringify`.

You'll also want to check the script deployment for the logging there to make sure there aren't any syntax errors or other exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the variable `line` at the beginning to `context.line` but the current context is `beforeSubmit`, therefore, it will be `undefined`. I can see that you're not using this variable anywhere but it is worth noting that. `line` is only available in Client contexts such as `fieldChange`, `validateField`, and such...

Also, in the last `setSublistValue` you're providing several parameters when the `Record.setSublistValue` method receives an object, just like you did on the previous `setSublistValue` calls.